# How to add markers in Google Maps in Flutter using the Geopoints data in Firebase Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to Flutter and Firebase. How can I add multiple markers in Google Maps in my Flutter Application from retrieving geopoints data in Firebase Firestore?

Here is the image of the document field in Firestore
[Firestore Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1roo.png)